# jQuery resize content DIV to place footer DIV directly below

Tags: jquery

I have a simple website which contains header, content and footer DIVS. The content DIV uses JQuery to scroll to the pages content but the footer stays below the largest sized .item div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.panel').click(function () {
        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });
});

function resizePanel() {
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({
        width: width,
        height: height
    });
    $('#mask').css({
        width: mask_width,
        height: height
    });
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
}
```

How do I resize the contents container (wrapper) to only be the height of the currently selected .item?

Thanks

Comment: could you throw up a simple http://jsfiddle.net for us to work with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2vsRD/

Comment: Are you wanting it so that the footer moves up and down depending on the height of the current .item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wC94k/1/

Assign from some obvious styling issues and a bit more grace in the dynamics of the footer moving I think this maybe what you want and set you on the right path.

This is the biggest chunk of new code I added to your existing code

```
wrapperHeight = $('#wrapper').height();
itemHeight = $('div#'+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')).height();
newHeight = (wrapperHeight - itemHeight) * -1;

$('#wrapper').css('margin-bottom', newHeight+'px');
```

Comment: Thanks Banning, that's just what I was looking for!

Is it possible to apply the scrollTo function to this or would that need it's own wrapper?

Also if the content is longer then a page the scroll bar appears on all pages. How would you set overflow:hidden on just shorter pages?

I have updated your http://jsfiddle.net/wC94k/2/ to give an example of what I mean.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok I made something a little more elegant here... :)